# Add onClick on MapContainer in Component in 3.x

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm using the following versions:

```
"leaflet": "^1.7.1",
"react-leaflet": "^3.0.2",
```

I want to perform some action on map-click, e.g. add a marker.

I tried the [stateless component approach](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-events) which seems to work, but I don't really like it for several reasons.

I tried using `eventHandlers` attribute:

```
  render() {
    return <div>
          <MapContainer center={[ 48, 11 ]} zoom={10} scrollWheelZoom={true} eventHandlers={{
            click: () => {
              console.log('map clicked')
            },
          }}>
            <TileLayer .../>
          </MapContainer>
        </div>
  }
```

but it never fires.

I also read about [MapConsumer](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map#mapconsumer) but can't find good examples to it.

Any hints on building in onClick event handler are appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `eventHandlers`, although it is available as a prop on `MapContainer` (if you press ctlr + space on vscode f.i it will pop up) it is not available in the official [API](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map) and is intended only for child components of `MapContainer`, see [here](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/779) and here for [Marker](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-components).

what you want to achieve can be implemented using `useMapEvents` on a separate comp and then included as a child on `MapContainer`:

```
function App() {
  function MyComponent() {
    const map = useMapEvents({
      click: (e) => {
        const { lat, lng } = e.latlng;
        L.marker([lat, lng], { icon }).addTo(map);
      }
    });
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <MapContainer center={[50.5, 30.5]} zoom={13} style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      <MyComponent />
    </MapContainer>
  );
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/add-onclick-on-mapcontainer-in-react-leaflet-v-3x-4r7tc)

Another approach is listen to `whenReady` prop (not officially documented but seems to work similarly to `whenCreated` prop but map instance is accessible via `object.target`) on `MapContainer`:

```
<MapContainer
      center={[50.5, 30.5]}
      zoom={13}
      style={{ height: "100vh" }}
      whenReady={(map) => {
        console.log(map);
        map.target.on("click", function (e) {
          const { lat, lng } = e.latlng;
          L.marker([lat, lng], { icon }).addTo(map.target);
        });
      }}
    >
    ...
</MapContainer>
```

3rd approach is to use `MapConsumer` as a child of `MapContainer` ([docs](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map#mapconsumer)):

```
<MapContainer center={[50.5, 30.5]} zoom={13}>
     <MapConsumer>
            {(map) => {
              console.log("map center:", map.getCenter());
              map.on("click", function (e) {
                const { lat, lng } = e.latlng;
                L.marker([lat, lng], { icon }).addTo(map);
              });
              return null;
            }}
     </MapConsumer>
</MapContainer>
```

4th approach is to use `whenCreated` prop (officially documented) on `MapContainer`:

```
<MapContainer
      center={[50.5, 30.5]}
      zoom={13}
      style={{ height: "100vh" }}
      whenCreated={(map) => {
        map.on("click", function (e) {
          const { lat, lng } = e.latlng;
          L.marker([lat, lng], { icon }).addTo(map.target);
        });
      }}
    >
...
```

Comment: this is what I have atm

Comment: I added two more ways. Have a look

Comment: The approach with `whenReady` seems to be removed in 3.0.2. Also the documentation redirects the search result to 404...

Comment: `whenReady` is there, you can find the prop documented [here](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map).

Comment: Ok indeed it is present, I was confused by the Typescript messages. The type says nog argument is passed to the callback function. Are you sure about this argument?

Comment: You are right that is not documented on the docs however it exists, try it on the above demo. There is an object: `{ target } ` there available which is an instance of the map.

Comment: Replace `whenReady` with `whenCreated` to get the map object